# XAML keyboard custom scopes or a forcing layout?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

The XAML text controls give a rather small amount of customization in terms of scopes. I have a MonoGame project that requires some text input and I want to limit the character set to what's in the SpriteFont. Given the nature of the XAML keyboard, pretty much anything can come out of it.

If custom scopes aren't possible per se, are there alternative solutions to for example force a certain keyboard layout and adjust the SpriteFont to that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom scopes are not possible.

Suggestion: use the default keyboard or one closest to giving all possible values to a `SpriteFont`. Then override `KeyUp` and them limit or remove the offending characters which are not found in the `SpriteFont` as the user types.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this would probably be the way I'd have to go. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to force a layout like UK or something?

Comment: @Muhwu interesting thought, but what differentiates a UK keyboard from US except the currency symbols. Only Hanja and katakana as far as I can see. [InputScopeNameValue Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: UK was just an example. The problem is that we have a SpriteFont in a MonoGame (Multiplatform XNA implementation) which requires character sets to be chosen in order to generate a sprite sheet of the font. So for inserting stuff like nicknames, it gets really hairy really fast if he have to support the whole UNICODE character set basically. Furthermore, blocking the input from visible buttons is apparently NOT an option.

Comment: @Muhwu I would then recommend that you create a custom textbox control (or derive from the original) which brings up your own custom keyboard. It is more work of course, but may pay off dividends going forward once in place. Then only thing which could put a damper on that is that WP8.1 has the swiping ability with the keyboard.